# Open Windows native exe program via xdg-open in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdgutils

When using `man` in Linux, many commands list URLs, which in some terminals like `gnome-terminal` or `terminator` are clickable.

For example, `man ls` shows:

[image: A clickable URL when hovering over with the mouse]

Which allows to click on http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils.

Clicking on it in [Gnome terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io) under WSL makes it hung.
And shows this output in the terminal that started terminator:

```
etomort@ES-00002604:/mnt/c/Users/etomort
$ /usr/bin/xdg-open: 782: /usr/bin/xdg-open: : Permission denied
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: x-www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: firefox: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: google-chrome: not found


[1]+  Stopped                 terminator  (wd: ~)
(wd now: /mnt/c/Users/etomort)
[2]   Done                    terminator
```

Is there a way to make `xdg-open` in WSL to call a Windows exe program?

Note: [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510624/ubuntu-for-windows-cant-open-pdf-files-via-xdg-open/513388) is related but more specific.
And the only answer is not useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue with Hashicorp Vault in WSL.

I created a script that basically forwards `xdg-open` to `powershell -c start`

Not tested much though.

```sh
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/xdg-open <<EOF
#!/bin/sh

powershell.exe -c start "'\$@'"
EOF
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xdg-open
```

Cheers
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Try using `wslview` instead of `xdg-open`, it works in Windows 10 wsl.

Install with:

```
sudo apt install wslu
```

source: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/wslview.1.html

Comment: Since I needed `xdg-open` I made it a link to the-just-installed `wslview`:   
```shell
sudo ln -s $(which wslview) /usr/local/bin/xdg-open
```